# HTML5 input type number weird behaviour after "9"

Tags: jquery, forms, html, input

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aleation/sfGBV/)

So I have 2 fields, Bathrooms and (bathrooms) en suite.

I limited it so the en suite field can never be greater than bathrooms, and if you lower bathroom's value it changes the ensuite value so it stay the same.

The script is actually simple and works good, but I noticed that if I put on bathrooms number a value  equal or higher than 9, it starts acting weird. If bathrooms is 15 for example, ensuite will jump straight from 1 to 15, and if you lower bathrooms it doesn't work anymore, it act like 20 or 2000 = 2 actually, ignoring the rest of the digits and taking the value of the first digit only.

html:

```
<label for="fbathrooms">Bathrooms</label><input id="fbathrooms" name="fbathrooms" type="number" min="0"/><br/>
<label for="fensuite" style="display:none">En Suite</label><input id="fensuite" name="fensuite" type="number" min="0" style="display:none;"/>​
```

code:

```
function bathroomsTrigger(){
    if($('#fbathrooms').val() > 0){
        $('#fensuite').slideDown('fast');
        $('label[for="fensuite"]').slideDown('fast');
    } else {
        $('#fensuite').slideUp('fast');
        $('label[for="fensuite"]').slideUp('fast');
        $('#fensuite').val(0);
    }

    if($('#fensuite').val() > $('#fbathrooms').val()){
        $('#fensuite').val($('#fbathrooms').val());
    }
}

function ensuiteTrigger(){
    if($('#fensuite').val() > $('#fbathrooms').val()){
        $('#fensuite').val($('#fbathrooms').val());
    }
}

$('#fbathrooms').keyup(bathroomsTrigger);
$('#fbathrooms').change(bathroomsTrigger);

$('#fensuite').keyup(ensuiteTrigger);
$('#fensuite').change(ensuiteTrigger);​
```

Driving me crazy, have been tweaking around for hours already xD

Help will be very appreciated.

(could it be an html5 bug?)

Comment: I can't actually see any of these errors you are talking about in the jsFiddle..

Comment: what aleation didn't specify was that you need to be using a browser such as Google Chrome (and NOT firefox), that lets you increment HTML5 inputs of type="number" using up/down arrows that appear next to the control. You had to increase the number of bathrooms to beyond about 20 and then start incrementing the number of en-suites and it would eventually jump from a small number of en-suites to the much larger number of bathrooms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is in your ensuite trigger, you have not parsed the string value to integer for the greater than comparison.

change:

```
$('#fensuite').val() > $('#fbathrooms').val()
```

to:

```
parseInt($('#fensuite').val()) > parseInt($('#fbathrooms').val())
```

Comment: That worked perfect! thank you for the quick answer. I feel ashamed of not seeing that xD (not very expert in javascript yet :/)

Comment: No problem, easy mistake to make. Please specify which browser you are using in future as I believe a number of users with Firefox (such as myself before trying chrome) couldn't recreate your issue.

Comment: @killercowuk Why does it only fail after 9?

Comment: @Cyle MDN's JavaScript reference says, strings if compared using Comparison Operators are sorted based on "standard lexicographical ordering, using Unicode values". Therefore, as "9" comes AFTER "1" alphabetically, "9" would actually be GREATER THAN "10" when ordered alphabetically (or in this case unicode-value-ly). All single digit numbers lower than 9 as a string would still be alphabetically LESS THAN 9, so the above logic appears to work until you hit double-digit numbers. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators